# Return to mainview Xcode4

Tags: view, xcode4

I am developing an application which has several views. I create different xib & view controller for each view. To open each view on button click using code:

```
-(IBAction)NextView{
    NextViewController *screen = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
[screen release];   
}
```

I use the same method from that view to open the next. To close a view I use:

```
-(IBAction)ReturnMainMenu {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

How can I come back to the main view from the last view (say 4th view) from a button to start again, instead of closing each with button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Also the method returns an NSArray of the controllers that were popped if you need to keep a track, like:

```
NSArray *poppedControllers = [self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: sorry that don't help. i tried the one below too, but won't help

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(patchSelector) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];

Comment: -(void)patchSelector{
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    }

Comment: is any thing to do with [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];

Comment: Yes. Why don't you use `pushViewController:animated:` instead of modal view controllers? (Modals are best for views that will be presented and then dismissed - not for drilling down a view hierarchy)

Comment: suceeded with some logic by NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers; if(//logic) [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];